# Does Thunderbird work with Exchange account

Tags: email, exchange, thunderbird

Has anyone got Thunderbird working with an Exchange account?

I downloaded and installed it yesterday and entered in my credentials and it failed.  The advanced setup has options for IMAP and SMTP but nothing for Exchange.

My Exchange account does not offer POP or IMAP

If Thunderbird does not support it out of the box is there an alternative email client apart from Outlook that supports Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Exchange servers also support POP and IMAP connections. Therefore, non-Outlook clients such as Entourage or Thunderbird can be used. However, this will limit the benefits of the Exchange service.

The only open source client i know working with Exchange protocol is Evolution with the with its Exchange Connector developed by Novell some times ago...

Answer (score 4):

This is a function of how your Exchange server is configured and whether your account allows POP3 or IMAP connections. Check with your administrator, but in general, Thunderbird can work. There are some caveats, though. No calendar, no easy export, there are some additional config needs for IMAP connections. Maybe see if Outlook Web Access is enabled.

Comment: can web or cloud based office 365 be configured to allow IMAP as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Outlook Web Access (OWA) you can also use DavMail http://davmail.sourceforge.net/ which is a Java application that "translates" the Web Access into a fully compliant mail stack (IMAP, SMTP, CalDav, LDAP, CardDav, ...).

Answer (score -1):

A log time past from the question...

Just for record... by this time I found this links.

Maybe this can be helpful to someone.

Provide connector to Exchange Server - Calendar not yet implemented.

http://thunderbirdtweaks.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/thunderbird-and-exchange-owa.html

At the bottom is a link to the Thunderbird Plugin.

One more useful link.
Calendar provider for Exchange 2007/2010/2013

http://crimsonfu.github.io/2012/03/27/lightning-exchange-provider.html

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please edit your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to include the information from your linked source so that it will remain useful to other users even if the link becomes inaccessible in the future.