# Remote Email Access?

Tags: email, exchange, remote-access, email-client, mobile-phone

I have remote email access from an iPhone or my Android phone, but I cannot setup a Windows Email Client to check my email using the exact same information I provided in my phones.

The email system is an Exchange 2003 and I hate using the cheap Outlook Web App that it has.

User: user@domain.com
Password: 1234
Server: mail.domain.com

And that works for they phones.

So why can't I get it to work on my email client? 
I've tried it with outlook 2003, 2007 and 2010 and none of them work.

Maybe a DNS problem?

Comment: Do you know if the Exchange server allows POP3 or IMAP connections? Windows Live Mail does not directly support the Exchange protocol. See also: http://superuser.com/q/353153/15210

Comment: What is the client you are trying?

Comment: What is the email service you are connecting to?

Comment: I dont know if it allows for POP or IMAP, do you know where I can look on the server for those settings?

Updated original post with email clients I've tried. I'm connecting to an Exchange 2003 server.

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Unable to connect to server. Our MX record points to spam.domain.com and that is a spam filter device then it goes to our exchange box.

Comment: Did you check the encryption settings? You may need to enable SSL/TLS and/or enable [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Password_Authentication).